# Making Oracle DB connection Dynnamically in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

Connecting to database dynamically jsp

Hi, I'm trying to make connection to database dynamically.
So when user clicks link from index page, it will send parameter "OS"
so my test page will receive parameter OS, looks for matchs in textfile that has list of database information like

```
XP-jdbc:oracle:thin@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:XPXP1-XP_user-XP_pass
W7-jdbc:oracle:thin@YY.YYY.YY.YY:YYYY:W7W71-W7_user-W7_pass
MAC-jdbc:oracle:thin@ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ:ZZZZ:MACO1-MAC_user-MAC_pass
LINNUX-jdbc:oracle:thin@AA.AAA.A.AA:AAAA:LINN1-LINNUX_user-LINNUX_ph1
```

my attempt:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("OS");
try{
    String db = "";
    String[] temp1;
    String dblist = root + "\\" + "dblist.txt";
    BufferedReader dbin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dblist));
    while ((db = dbin.readLine()) != null){
        temp1=db.split("-");
        if ((temp1[0].equals(userName))){
             connString = temp1[1].toString();
             connUser = temp1[2].toString();
             connPass = temp1[3].toString();
        }
     }
     dbin.close();
}catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}

try{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, connUser, connPass);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

}
```

My problem is, this doesn't work!
I get java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified  when i open my web page....
What did i have wrong?

Apparently my property file was corrutped >.> that was the reason why my property file only read half of it's components...thanks for your help anyways

Comment: if you debug connString, connUser, and connPass before the getConnection() call, what are their values?

Comment: they do have correct value idk why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use **Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");** instead of **DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());**

Also,have you checked if YY.YYY.YY.YY:YYYY is replaced by proper IP and port?

Comment: does it make difference? and yes, IP and port is correct if i try to connect individually